# Mono for Android JavaList convert to List and viceversa

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.android

How can I **convert**  **JavaList** to **List** and vice-versa? I would like to use LINQ, but I cannot do this with JavaList since i cannot cast from anything to JavaList. Any suggestions how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have problems switching between the JavaList and List for example in this way:

```
        JavaList<int> a = new JavaList<int>{4, 3, 2, 1};
        List<int> b = a.Where(v => v >= 2).ToList();
        JavaList<int> c = new JavaList<int>(b);
```

However it is good to be aware of the consequences, take a look at [Chapter 4 in Xamarin API Design](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/api_design).